# Meaning of 'pos' in syntax tree

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

I have just started to learn SML and I am feeling confused by the following code:

```
type pos = int
datatype prog= Prog of statement option
    and statement =... some code..
    and expression =
         VarExp of symbol * pos
         | IntExp of int * pos
         | BoolExp of bool * pos
         | BopExp of exp * oper * exp * pos
         | UopExp of oper * exp * pos
```

What I am not able to understand is the use of  `pos`. Shouldn't the signature be like `BopExp of exp * oper * exp` instead of `BopExp of exp * oper * exp * pos` ?

Comment: A wild guess is that `pos` represents a position of some kind (line number or character offset or something), possibly in order to be able to produce reasonable error messages. It will most likely become clear if you read the explanation and use of the type.

Comment: This could be the code for `ML-YACC`. The `pos` is passed for error reporting.

Comment: While a parser finds a parsing error, it needs to tell the programmer where the mistake arises. I think this is why we need `pos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since John, molbdnilo and Tai already answered you in comments by saying that *pos* is probably some kind of position, suggesting that the textual representation of the syntactic element resides at the *pos*'th character in a file, here's some more thoughts:

A syntax tree might be annotated with all kinds of information. The parser usually keeps the position for error reporting. So does a static type-checker, but it might also keep inferred type information that it can pass onto itself or a subsequent code-generating phase.

What you can do is parameterise your syntax tree:

```
datatype 'a prog = Prog of 'a stmt list
and 'a stmt = AssignStmt of symbol * 'a exp * 'a
            | PrintStmt of 'a exp * 'a
and 'a exp = VarExp of symbol * 'a
           | IntExp of int * 'a
           | BoolExp of bool * 'a
           | BopExp of 'a exp * oper * 'a exp * 'a
           | UopExp of oper * 'a exp * 'a
```

Then a program like *x := 2 + true;* might first be parsed and annotated as a *pos prog*:

```
type pos = int
val hello = Prog [AssignStmt ("x", BopExp (IntExp (2, 6), "+",
                                           BoolExp (true, 10),
                                           6),
                              0)
                 ]
```

which says that the assignment is found at position 0, the expression *2 + true* is found at position 6, the integer *2* at position 6, and the boolean *true* at position 10. When you get to type-checking, you might instead want a *(pos × typ) prog*:

```
type typ = Int | Bool | None | Conflict of typ list * typ
val hello = Prog [AssignStmt ("x", BopExp (IntExp (2, (6, Int)), "+",
                                           BoolExp (true, (10, Bool)),
                                           (6, Conflict ([Int, Bool], Int)),
                              (0, None)
                 ]
```

which retains the position information for decent error reporting (that's still necessary if there's a type error), but also keeps information about where there are conflicting types, e.g. `Conflict ([Int, Bool], Int)` was meant to suggest that while it *expects* `Int`, it can't derive that because of conflicting types `Int` and `Bool`.

Then you only ever need one syntax tree definition for positions, types, registers, whatever you can come up with to annotate your syntactic elements with.